# Win 7: Cannot access SSL sites

Tags: windows-7, internet, ssl

I haven't been able to access any site using ssl since yesterday. When I, for example, try to visit Gmail nothing happens expect a blank screen.

I have tried fixing this by checking that date/time is correct (it- is), by clearing ssl certificates in IE, and re-registering dll files for IE per [Microsoft's instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813444).

The only thing that can cause this, I believe, is yesterday's Windows update.

Comment: Does this also happen in other browsers, I.E. Firefox, Opera or Chrome?

Comment: Yes, this happens in all browsers i have: opera, firefox, chrome, ie.

Comment: @Baht1 - It sounds like you have been infected by a malicious file if this is happens when using different browsers.  I can guarantee you that yeterday's update is unlikely the cause of this.  It wouldn't shocking to have malware that setups a proxy connection on the most popular browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a temporary solution.

I have a cheap netgear router that sits between the network and the internet. I simply forwarded the port 443 (the default ssl port) to the ip of my computer (192.168.0.8) and now I can once again visit sites using SSL. Mediocre success. I have no idea why this is needed but it beats blowing my brains out. Tada, useless lusers.

Comment: This does not make sense, port 443 is the OUTGOING port. I have never seen a "Cheep netgear router" that blocks outgoing ports, only incoming, I think something else is going on, you may have some kind virus/malware infection.